# How to transfer the control from my boot loader to the application located in hard drive

Tags: assembly, x86, hard-drive, bootloader, bios

I am using NASM on Windows and testing it on VMware, and successfully made my boot loader. Now I want that my boot loader transfers the control to some application (say I want to simulate the work of kernel), but instead of kernel I want to load some app? Can you give me some hint how to locate the file in HDD in terms of sector, head etc and then load into ram?

I know that kernel is located at address 2000h also an interrupt 13h which loads the harddisk information into RAM, but how to find the exact sector, head for that file?

Comment: you might find this of use: http://wiki.osdev.org/Rolling_Your_Own_Bootloader#How_do_I_actually_load_bytes

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the [Logical Block Addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing) extensions, then loading a sector into memory is much easier. You'd still be using the INT 0x13 interrupt, but with `AH` set to [`0x42`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13#INT_13h_AH.3D42h:_Extended_Read_Sectors_From_Drive). You simply specify the starting sector index and the number of consecutive sectors you want to load and where.

Without implementing a file system, you must place the application at some known offset from the start of your disk image. Once loaded, you simply jump to the address you loaded the sectors to.

Getting a single detail wrong will triple fault the emulated CPU, so make sure you have a working [print string function](http://www.supernovah.com/Tutorials/BootSector3.php) at hand.

---

The BIOS will load your boot loader from sector 0 to `0x7c00`. You could simply place your application at some multiple of the sector size. Assuming a sector size of 512 bytes, then it should look something like this:

- Sector 0 (offset 0): boot loader -> `0x7c00`
- Sector 1 (offset 512): application -> `0x7e00` or any address of your choosing

If you load your application to `0x7e00`, then you just do `jmp 0x0:0x7e00` to run it.

I don't know any tools for Windows to create the disk image, but you could always use the assembler to pad the offsets correctly if you want everything in the same file.

---

Since I have code from a boot loader I wrote some time ago, I might as well share some examples (NASM syntax):

```
BITS 16

ORG 0x7c00

entry:
    xor ax, ax      ; Explicitly set DS=0 
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax      ; Set SS:SP out the way (below the bootloader) at 0x0000:0x7c00
    mov sp, 0x7c00

    mov ah, 0x42 ; set to lba extended read
    mov dl, 0x80 ; first hard drive
    mov si, dap  ; address of disk address package

    int 0x13     ; execute

    jc .load_failed ; do something on failure

    jmp 0x0:0x7e00 ; jump to the destination address


ALIGN 16

; this is the disk address package used by the lba extensions
dap:
db 0x10   ; size of this package
db 0x0    ; reserved
dw 0x1    ; number of sectors to load
dd 0x7e00 ; destination address
dq 0x1    ; sector index to load

; pad to assumed sector size. this will overwrite the partition table
TIMES 510 - ($ - $$) db 0

; boot signature
dw 0xaa55

; either write your app here or concatenate a separate .bin file
```

Comment: If i am doing it on .iso (image file) so what i have to do? i mean in my iso on my first sector their is the boot loader so in my next sector the .bin file of my application? so it is on 2nd sector corresponding to that iso file? So whats step i have to do in order to run that application?

Comment: @user2984278 Yes. I expanded my answer to make it more clear. You need to use the INT 0x13 AH=0x42 interrupt to load the sector(s) you stored the application in to some available address below the 1 MiB mark assuming you're still in real mode with A20-line disabled.

Comment: @user2984278 I added an example that should explain everything.